# Detect line split from gmail in clipboard (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, gmail, clipboard, paste

I'm trying to allow users to paste from gmail into a field, and detect line breaks.  It does not need to be a text area, I just want to detect the line breaks.

The problem is that when a user pastes something like below...clipboard does not seem to detect the break (even if user had hit enter in gmail)

```
Item 1 
Item 2 
Item 3
```

To detect it, the user seems to have to have hit enter twice...like below:

```
Item 1

Item 2

Item 3
```

Is there a way to detect line breaks from gmail?

Below seems to work for notepad, inbox and other areas where I copy from.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26k9du)

Component:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="paste items here" (paste)="onPaste(i, $event, $event)">

<div *ngIf="itemArray.length > 0">
Item list:
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

TS:

```
itemArray = [];

  onPaste(i, event: ClipboardEvent, value) {
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
    let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text/plain').split("\n");
    pastedText.forEach(item => {
      item = item.toString()
      item = item.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s\r|\r)/gm, "")
      this.itemArray.push(item) 
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the pasted text has line breaks that are just carriage return (\r). This is not transported into an input field. Looks like just \n is passing. I found an approach that uses a textarea which takes over the line feeds independent on \r or \n or \r\n. Then use the input event of the textarea to read the text from it. So it is a kind of proxy for the clipboard. I know this is not a proper solution but may help a little.

I have modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7prvg).

Comment: Thanks.  Is that working for you when pasting from gmail?  I tried that as well, but does not seem to split the lines when pasting from gmail into the textarea.  The results still show as 'Item 1Item 2Item 3' unless I hit enter twice between items in gmail (same as problem in my question)

Comment: I investigated a little. The Gmail editor puts every line into a div tag. If you hit enter again then it inserts a line <div><br></div> in which the <br> is transformed to a CRLF when you copy to your target field. The <div> is ignored. I fear you will not find a proper solution for that. The only thing you could try is to use a richtext editor to copy to. Maybe then the html is also transported.

Comment: Oof.  Is there a way to detect </div> in an input field?  Google sheets seems to detect the line break fine, so I'm wondering if there's a workaround for standard text input fields

Comment: I found another solution. It is an editable div. It can take html and then you can get the innerHTML from it and parse: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkkqej

Comment: Wow.  Creative solution!  I do need it as an input field, because have to do validation etc. within a reactive form.  However, will give you the 50 points if no other answer comes for the input field.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<p>{{item}} </p>`  instead of `{{item}}`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
    <p>{{item}} </p> 
</div>
```

[stackBlitz answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqzmvx)

hope this will helps ...!

Comment: Thanks, but if you try copying and pasting from gmail, you'll see that the output still appears as one line.

Comment: @user749798 -can you give some sample inputs, it will more helpful, because this works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @chathuran, I did above.  In gmail, type 'Item 1'<hit enter once>'Item 2'<hit enter once>'Item 3'<hit enter once>.  Even though each item will be on a different line, when you copy that from gmail and paste the results in an input field, the clipboard data from the paste is captured as one line, rather than splitting into 3